# Flutter Webview: Could cascading calls interfere with NavigationDelegate?

Tags: flutter, webview

Could cascading statements (e.g. `controller..setJavascriptMode()..setNavigationDelegate()..loadRequest()`) in a Flutter Webview fail to set NavigationDelegate prior to loadUrl? I ask because both setNavigationDelegate and loadUrl return a future.